# RFIDIOt with libNFC on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, python-2.7, dll, rfid, lib-nfc

I'm trying to use RFIDIOt with libnfc-1.7.0-rc7 on Windows 7 64 bit. I compiled dll from sources and it works perfect with programs like nfc-poll.exe and so on.

But now I want to write a program on python 2.7 with libNFC. I want to use RFIDIOt to communicate with my PN532_uart reader, but I can't run example program on windows.

When I try to run: `python cardselect.py -R RFIDIOt.rfidiot.READER_LIBNFC`

I get an Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cardselect.py", line 25, in <module>
    import rfidiot
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\RFIDIOt-master\rfidiot\__init__.py", line 1
94, in <module>
    card= RFIDIOt.rfidiot(readernum,readertype,line,speed,timeout,rfidiotglobals
.Debug,noinit,nfcreader)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\RFIDIOt-master\rfidiot\RFIDIOt.py", line 16
3, in __init__
    self.nfc = pynfc.NFC(self.NFCReader)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\RFIDIOt-master\rfidiot\pynfc.py", line 283,
 in __init__
    self.configure(nfcreader)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\RFIDIOt-master\rfidiot\pynfc.py", line 352,
 in configure
    self.LIBNFC_READER= self.libnfc.nfc_device_get_name(self.device)
ValueError: invalid string pointer 0x00000010
```

I don't have an idea how to fix it... Please anybody help me! 
This problem is only on Windows, on Linux all works great, but I want to use my program on Windows.

How do I fix this error?

I'm using python 2.7, libNFC-1.7.0-rc7, Windows 7 x64 and pn532_uart reader on COM1.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I solved this problem by accident. I launched this command: `python cardselect.py -R RFIDIOt.rfidiot.READER_LIBNFC` as administrator. This idea went to me when I was reading [this.](http://winappdbg.sourceforge.net/doc/v1.5/reference/winappdbg.win32.advapi32-pysrc.html)

P.S.: sorry for my English. I hope it will helpful for somebody.